# Arranging 4 histogram plots in a 2x2 facet grid

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, facet, facet-grid

## The issue

I have a dataframe with two columns: color and values.

Color can be red, yellow, green and black. For each of these 4 colors, I need to plot an histogram with the distribution of "values". I would like the plots to be arranged in a 2x2 grid.

## What I would like to do

I would like to automate the creation of the plots - with the FacetGrid function or some equivalent.

In the examples I have seen, histogram are facetted by subsets of data, with one variable over the columns and one over the row. E.g here: https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/faceted_histogram.html there are 3 species, 2 sexes, and 6 charts.

## What I have tried but doesn't work

I have tried the FacetGrid function, but it produces 4 identical charts. It is clear I am doing something wrong when I define the FacetGrid or call the map() method, but I'm not sure what.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df=pd.DataFrame()
df['values'] = np.hstack([np.ones(25),
                          np.arange(200,225),
                          np.ones(25) *5,
                          np.linspace(500,550,25)])
df['category'] = np.repeat(['red','yellow','green','black'],25)

fig = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='category', col_wrap=2)
fig.map(sns.histplot, data = df, x='values', stat='density' )
```

In my data, there is only one categorical variable, not 2. This categorical variable can take 4 values and I'd like the plots in a 2x2 grid.

## What I have got to work

I can create a figure with 2x2 subplots, and manually populate each of the 4 axes. It works, but it's neither elegant nor efficient

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df=pd.DataFrame()
df['values'] = np.hstack([np.ones(25),
                          np.arange(200,225),
                          np.ones(25) *5,
                          np.linspace(500,550,25)])
df['category'] = np.repeat(['red','yellow','green','black'],25)

fig2, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
categories = np.array([['red','yellow'],['green', 'black']])

for r in range(2):
    for c in range(2):
        cat = categories[r,c]
        print(cat)
        sns.histplot(df.query("category == @cat"), x="values", kde= True, stat='density', bins =10, ax = ax[r,c])

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Change to `fig = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='category', col_wrap=2, sharex=False, sharey=False)
fig.map_dataframe(sns.histplot, data = df, x='values', stat='density', bins=10)`

Comment: @HMH1013 I have tried but I get the same result: 4 identical plots

Comment: This is the figure I got :   https://imgtr.ee/i/capture.0VRL1. Which is the same figure as you plot with the for loop.   The code is as below : `fig = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='category', col_wrap=2, sharex=False, sharey=False) ` and `fig.map_dataframe(sns.histplot, data = df, x='values', stat='density', bins=10)` . Attention it's `fig.map_dataframe` not `fig.map`

Comment: Ah, I had confused map with map_dataframe. if you type it as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: It should be `g = sns.displot(kind='hist', data=df, x='values', col='category', col_wrap=2, bins=10, stat='density', kde=True)`. Please review [`seaborn.FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) and note the **Warning**. In most cases it will be better to use a figure-level function (e.g. [`displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html)).

Comment: remove df in `histplot`: `fig.map(sns.histplot, 'values', stat='density')`